# Blackberry video thumbnail display prob

Tags: blackberry, video

In my Blackberry app, I want to display a screen with a video and a lebel field. I am using the following code for video display and auto play.

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();

Player player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/videos/sample.3gp");

player.realize();

videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");

Field videoField = (Field) videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE,"net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");

VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl) player.getControl("VolumeControl");
volume.setLevel(30);

player.start();

vfm.add(videoField);
..................
......................
.............
add(vfm);
```

It is working well. But, when the video is over, it is showing a black screen, but I want to display the first screen when the display is over and video can be replayed if user wants.

What change is needed in my code to achieve this feature?